# Is there no prompt in the Android 4.x spinner anymore?

Tags: android, spinner

I'm new to Android development and found that I can setup a `android:prompt` attribute to a `Spinner` widget. Like so in my `layout/my_layout_fragment.xml`:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/boxFunction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_row="14"
    android:entries="@array/function_options"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:prompt="@string/function_prompt" />
```

I found several screenshots from the Android 2.x epoch which clearly shows the prompt, but I haven't had any luck finding any 4.x screenshots which shows me the prompt. And my compiled app on Android doesn't show it either.

Was the prompt deprecated in 4.x (and if so, where can I get the deprecated information)? Or did I miss something?

Comment: You may be hardcodeing the android:prompt="value" Try using the @string/value from string folder. I was facing the same issue.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I don't think it is deprecated. Maybe from 4.0 it depends on another attribute called

> android:spinnerMode

Here is a example which shows you how the prompt works with Spinner Mode attribute.

And before that let me make it clear that,**spinnerMode** can be set to either **dialog** or **dropdown**.

```
<Spinner  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/app_name"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>



<Spinner  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/app_name"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
    />
```

As you can see the first spinner has the [spinnerMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android:spinnerMode) set to dialog and the next spinner set to dropdown.

here are the outputs,

**Dialog Mode**

[image]

**drop Down**

[image]

The prompt title I have used here is "Locale Test". Thought I have set it to both the spinners it is visible only in Dialog Mode spinner. So I think it speaks for it.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't show up when I add the `spinnerMode` attribute. Do you know if it depends on the used theme? I use the `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` theme.

Comment: yes it depends. Holo is the one which comes with drop down type. Maybe you should try removing the holo theme.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up. I'll rather not get rid of the theme. I'll just skip the prompt or perhaps I'll will dive into header views on the `ListPopUpWindow`.

Comment: its fine then. I am not familiar with those yet. But its good to use Holo theme :)